# routing not working my url is not changing when i click on li tag

Tags: reactjs

I have this `serch.js`  when I search and click on the `li` in search result I want to get redirected to `<InnerDetail />` but the URL does not change or I don't get redirected to this page

but manually if I type in the URL  `localhost/detiled/8`  i am retirected to to `<InnerDetail />` with id as 8

```
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const initialState = {
  idaddProducts: '',
};
const Searchclients = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(true);

  const [poName, pnName] = React.useState(initialState);
  const [showSerch, setShowSerch] = React.useState([]);
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedSuggestion, setSelectedSuggestion] = React.useState(0);
  const [displaySuggestions, setDisplaySuggestions] = React.useState(false);

  const suggestions = [];
  showSerch.forEach(function (data) {
    suggestions.push(data);
  });

  const onChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(value);
    setShowResults(false);

    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      (suggestion) =>
        suggestion.firstname
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
        suggestion.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );

    setFilteredSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    setDisplaySuggestions(true);
  };

  const onSelectSuggestion = (index) => {
    setSelectedSuggestion(index);
    setInputValue(filteredSuggestions[index]);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]);
    setDisplaySuggestions(false);
  };

  const SuggestionsList = (props) => {
    // console.log(props);

    const {
      suggestions,
      inputValue,

      onSelectSuggestion,
      displaySuggestions,
      selectedSuggestion,
    } = props;

    if (inputValue && displaySuggestions) {
      if (suggestions.length > 0) {
        return (
          <ul className='suggestions-list' style={styles.ulstyle}>
            {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              // console.log(suggestions);
              const isSelected = selectedSuggestion === index;
              const classname = `suggestion ${isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}`;
              return (
                <Link to={`/detiled/${suggestion.id}`}>
                  {' '}
                  ///this link dont work
                  <li
                    style={styles.listyle}
                    // onMouseOver={{ background: "yellow" }}
                    key={index}
                    className={classname}
                  >
                    {suggestion.firstname}
                  </li>
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        return <div>No suggestions available...</div>;
      }
    }
    return <></>;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('all-doctors-list/').then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      // pnName(data.data);

      //  var stringdata = data;
      setShowSerch(data);

      //console.log(stringdata);
    });
    //  setShowSerch(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='note-container' style={styles.card}>
        <div style={styles.inner}>
          <p style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Search Doctors</p>
          <form className='search-form' style={{}}>
            {showResults ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                style={{ marginRight: '-23px' }}
                icon={faSearch}
              />
            ) : null}
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              value={inputValue}
              style={styles.input}
              type='Search'
            />

            <SuggestionsList
              inputValue={inputValue}
              selectedSuggestion={selectedSuggestion}
              onSelectSuggestion={onSelectSuggestion}
              displaySuggestions={displaySuggestions}
              suggestions={filteredSuggestions}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Searchclients;
```

navigation .js

```
<Route path='/detiled/:id'>
  <InnerDetail />
</Route>;
```

Comment: What's `nextPath` ? 
And it's "search" not "serch". "Detiled" is also weird.

Comment: i removed nextpath

Comment: Can you post your full `navigation.js` code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with map function. Do you have an "id" field in your database? because depending on the field name it can be "suggestion.id" or suggestion._id"

I think restructuring your code might solve the problem. Then you can add up error handlers (If I were you I wouldnt put `return` inside `if` statement for error handling. Instead, you can use `useState` and conditional rendering for error handling).

Restructuring your code like below might be useful, I put `map` function inside `return` and `key` attribute right after `map` function.

```
return(
  <div>{
    suggestions.map(suggestion => (
      <div className="anything" key={suggestion.id}>
        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none'}} to={`/suggestion/${suggestion.id}`}>
          <li>{suggestion.firstname}</li>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))
  }</div>
);
```